# How to return a struct's field from another struct's function?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have:

```
struct Vector {
    int a;
    int b;
}

struct Temp {
    Vector *array[5];

    int find() {
        return array[0].a;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error "Vector *Temp:: array[5]. Expression must have class type. How do I return the fields of another struct from within a struct function?
Note: asked from my phone. Sorry if there are any format issues.

Comment: You need ';' after your structure declarations and array is an array of pointers so you need array[0]->a

Answer (score 1):

with the line

```
Vector *array[5];
```

You are declaring an array of 5 *pointers* to Vectors, not the structs themselves.

To fix this you should either switch to an array of structs

```
Vector array[5];
```

Or if you do *really* need an array of pointers then you should change your find function to return

```
return array[0]->a;
```

Note the use of the `->` operator here which dereferences the pointer to a struct and then accesses it's member.

Remember that if you go the pointer route you will also need to manually allocate memory for each of them as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector *array[5];
```

This is an array of pointers to Vector not Vector objects.

Therefore you need to use pointer notation to access Vector's fields like this:

```
array[0]->a;
```

Since your array only contains pointers you will need to make sure to allocate storage for each one.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    array[i] = new Vector;
```

Otherwise you can just define your array like so:

```
Vector array[5];
```

This is an array of Vector objects and I think that this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a vector of pointers, you'll need to use the `->` operator to access the members.

```
Vector *array[5];

int find() {
    return array[0]->a;  // Use -> operator.
}
```

You can use the `.` operator if you use a vector of objects.

```
Vector array[5];  // vector of object, not pointers.

int find() {
    return array[0].a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector *array[5];
```

is an array of pointers to `Vector`. Access to a would have to be

```
return array[0]->a;
```

to dereference the pointer to a `Vector` and get its `a` member. But that would have unpredictable results as the pointers were not assigned any storage to point at.

Do you perhaps mean,

```
Vector array[5];
```

to create an array of `Vector`s?